# Break text using based on width with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, split

I have an span and I want to break it based on its width using javascript, so if it has an width bigger than 100px I'd to split/break it.

For example, if the span has 220px, it would break twice where the 1st and 2nd line would have 100px and the third 20px.

Is that possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Please try with the below link. http://jayeshgoyani.blogspot.in/2012/04/how-to-wrap-word-in-radgrids-column-or.html

Comment: @APAD1 http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#min-max-widths `all elements but non-replaced inline elements, table rows, and row groups`

Comment: I'd like to use js because if the 2nd line breaks, I don't want to show the 3rd line, I want to put "..." in the end of 2nd.

Comment: @user2600853 Why in first place are you using an inline element as SPAN then??? As a good read: http://css-tricks.com/line-clampin/

Comment: Most of the techniques barely work..